# MQTT topics and uniqueness issue

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, mqtt

I'm experimenting a bit with MQTT and I've run into a bit of weirdness. It could be due to my specific setup but I thought I'd ask away anyway.

I'm using Node.JS and mqttjs as a broker. I'm also using the IBM ia92 testing client written in Java.

When I subscribe to a topic like `/system/app` and I then publish a message to `/system/appp` my client receives this message although the topic name is not the same. Note that if I publish to `/system/ap` I do not receive a message. Of course publishing to `/system/app` works fine.

Does this mean that MQTT "auto fills in" to something similar or is this a mistake in the client/broker? I'm aware of the `+` and `#` wildcards but this "feature/bug" is not known to me.

The broker I'm using can be found here:

https://github.com/adamvr/MQTT.js/blob/master/examples/server/orig.js

It has some weird regular expression on line 23 which I've tried to figure out why it's needed and what it does. Perhaps it could be the cause of a bug if this is not a feature? If anyone has any thoughts on this I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about MQTT, but the 'bug' seems to be caused by the fact that the regex are not anchored, so if the subscription topic name can be found within the topic name that is tested against it, the match will succeed (at the `test` on line 40).

If you add the end of string anchor `$` by changing line 23 from

```
 , reg = new RegExp(topic.replace('+', '[^\/]+').replace('#', '.+$'));
```

to

```
 , reg = new RegExp(topic.replace('+', '[^\/]+').replace('#', '.+') + '$');
```

it may prevent this behaviour.

I recommend that you open it as an issue at the github repo.

Comment: Thank you, I've raised the issue in the issue queue and we'll see how it plays out. Will accept answer as soon as it's all clear what's going on :)

Answer (score 1):

Agree that I'd raise an issue on the mqtt.js tracker.

I also recommend asking on the MQTT Google Group about this kind of protocol specification issue, and also testing the same thing against the rsmb and mosquitto brokers which are more-or-less the reference implementations.

FWIW, IA92 is both really really (really) old and outdated, and also has a questionable license. If you want a Java client for MQTT check out Eclipse Paho which is the current reference implementation.

Comment: Thank you, I've raised the issue in the issue queue and we'll see how it plays out. Also, thank you for the tip for Paho, I didn't know they  had a client that could be used for testing. Will look into it!

Comment: Paho doesn't currently have a standalone GUI like the one in IA92 (I raised a bug to say we need one!) but there's an Eclipse view you can use for testing. The mosquitto command line samples are also really handy.